# SQL Server - Dropping Temporary Table using "If ... Then" inside TRY and CATCH

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone explain why this code results in an error?

```
BEGIN TRY
    IF OBJECT_ID ('TEMPDB..#ABC') IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #ABC
    END;

    SELECT 1 AS A, 2 AS B 
    INTO #ABC;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH;

DROP TABLE #ABC;

BEGIN TRY
    IF OBJECT_ID ('TEMPDB..#ABC') IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #ABC
    END;

    SELECT 3 AS C, 4 AS D 
    INTO #ABC;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH;

SELECT * FROM #ABC;
```

The error occurs at the second TRY and CATCH statement showing that #ABC table already exists even though there is a drop statement before the second TRY block and even inside the second TRY, there is a "IF OBJECT_ID... THEN DROP" statement.

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Line XX
>   There is already an object named #ABC in the database

Comment: I do wonder - are you using some weird SKU of SQL Server where you have to pay additional licensing costs for each unique name used? Temp table names can be up to 116 characters long - why is it so important that both of the temp tables here use the *same* name?

Answer (score 1):

You need a "GO" between the two blocks, or SQL Server will try to execute the entire set of statements as a single entity.

Because there is DDL in the first section, it is not executed at the time the second statement is parsed.    By placing a "GO" after the end of the first CATCH, the script should execute fine.

Answer (score 1):

In a single batch you have two `INTO #ABC` so while compiling sql server doesn't consider on what conditions they are created it just throws that error thinking you are trying to create the same table twice.

```
BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN
     IF OBJECT_ID ('TEMPDB..#ABC') IS NOT NULL 
     DROP TABLE #ABC
     create table #ABC(A tinyint, b tinyint, c tinyint, d tinyint)
  END;
  Insert into #ABC(A, B)
  SELECT 1 AS A, 2 AS B 

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH;

BEGIN TRY
  Insert into #ABC(C, D)
  SELECT 3 AS C, 4 AS D 

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH;

SELECT * FROM #ABC;
```

If you don't want 4 columns in result, then create two intermediate temp tables and insert the result into intermediate temp tables and insert the result of both the tables into `#ABC`